# Join two tables where the other table has no equivalent value in the other table using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to join two tables where some rows does not have a value in the other table.

This is the first table:

```
ID      TDNO    lotNO   area    VALUE      DATE    MEMO    
------  ------  ------  ------  ---------  ------  --------
100     1       111     100     100.00     2015    ASDASD  
101     2       222     100     100.00     2015    SDFSDF  
102     3       333     200     100.00     2015    TEST    
103     4       444     200     200.00     2015    FOO     
104     5       555     330     200.00     2015    BAR     
105     100     100     100     11,000.00  2016    100
```

This is the second table:

```
tdno    hiid    sequence_no  
------  ------  -------------
100     qwerty              0
A) 1    qwerty              1
2       qwerty              2
3       qwerty              3
4       qwerty              4
5       qwerty              5
```

What I want is that I want to join the two tables but as you can see there is a row that has no value in the other table. How to join this?

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT 
  ht.ID,
  ht.TDNO,
  ht.lotNO,
  ht.area,
  FORMAT(ht.assess_value, 2) AS 'VALUE',
  ht.EFF AS 'DATE',
  ht.memoranda AS 'MEMO',
  ts.hiid,
  ts.sequence_no 
FROM
  history_table ht 
  RIGHT JOIN td_sequence ts 
    ON ts.`tdno` = ht.`TDNO` 
WHERE hiid = 'qwerty' 
  AND sequence_no >= '0'
  ORDER BY sequence_no ASC
```

And the result is like this:

```
ID      TDNO    lotNO   area    VALUE      DATE    MEMO    hiid    sequence_no  
------  ------  ------  ------  ---------  ------  ------  ------  -------------
105     100     100     100     11,000.00  100     100     qwerty              0
(NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)     (NULL)  (NULL)  qwerty              1
101     2       222     100     100.00     2015    SDFSDF  qwerty              2
102     3       333     200     100.00     2015    TEST    qwerty              3
103     4       444     200     200.00     2015    FOO     qwerty              4
104     5       555     330     200.00     2015    BAR     qwerty              5
```

What I want is like this:

```
ID      TDNO    lotNO   area    VALUE      DATE    MEMO    hiid    sequence_no  
------  ------  ------  ------  ---------  ------  ------  ------  -------------
105     100     100     100     11,000.00  100     100     qwerty              0
100     A) 1    111     100     100.00     2015    ASDASD  qwerty              1
101     2       222     100     100.00     2015    SDFSDF  qwerty              2
102     3       333     200     100.00     2015    TEST    qwerty              3
103     4       444     200     200.00     2015    FOO     qwerty              4
104     5       555     330     200.00     2015    BAR     qwerty              5
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: I can't see which row you mean

Comment: the `ID=100` with the `TDNO=1` and the `tdno=A) 1`. I want to link them because the data in `tdno=A) 1` is in `TDNO=1`

Comment: "A) 1" is a valid tdno? This sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: TDNO is a string so it is valid

Comment: is there any way to implement this? can you show me how?

Comment: It may be 'valid', but that doesn't mean it's not poor design.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way around:

```
...
FROM td_sequence ts
LEFT JOIN history_table ht  
ON ts.`tdno` = ht.`TDNO`
...
```

Comment: the result is still the same